# Can anyone suggest me at which case do we need to use Any * Any size class mode?

Tags: ios, class, layout, storyboard, size

1. Can anyone suggest me at which case do we need to use Any * Any  size class mode?
2. At which size class mode to be set when the app is build for compatible with both iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 0):

The two questions you're asking are very generic and exposes an important lack of understanding of how size classes work. Answering your questions would go somewhat like this:

1. In almost all cases
2. All size classes are important

I suggest starting [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started).

Take a look at this image:

[image]

If you use Any Width / Any Height it simply means that the constraints/views you are using will be 'installed' for all devices. If you use Compact Width / Regular Height, it means the constraints/views you are using will be installed for all iPhones when they are in portrait mode. If you use Regular / Regular, it means the constraints/views you are using will be installed only for iPads.

Note that when you add constraints and views in your storyboard / xib files, you will be able to toggle back and forth between different size classes to 'install' them for the correct size classes.

Hope this help and sends you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know what is size class ?
 Size classes are Apple's solution to the question "How can I easily work with so many different screen sizes and device orientations?" 
Size classes are the marquee feature of adaptive design. Using them allows you to eliminate code and logic that addressed multiple screen sizes, orientations, or specific devices.

Any * Any size used when your layout doesn’t change in any screen size.It also makes it easy to have just one interface for all of the devices available.When u want to make application for multiple device in that case we use Any * Any size.To know more refer apple documentation:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

To understand it completely make a demo using size classes.Refer:http://swiftiostutorials.com/using-size-classes-xcode-6/